# is it normal for gcloud to become unresponsive after being idled for a while?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I am able to successfuly connect to my instance at Google Cloud Platform using their gcloud command line tool, yet I find that if I go out to have a dinner or something, after I come back, the whole terminal will become unresponsive and I have to terminate the whole thing and restart again. My laptop is pretty old and I have the misfortune of living in a country where Google is banned ( but not the IP address where my website is hosted) But this shouldn't be a problem as I am running a VPN and I have no problem connecting to my instance at first. It is pretty slow but responsive, until it isn't if I leave it for a while. please let me know how I can assist in debugging in the comment. I am running debian on GCP and my lattop is Macbook pro mid 2014 catalina

Comment: IIUC you're using `gcloud compute ssh ....` to connect to your instance. If so, `gcloud` is leveraging your OS` ssh binary and so the issue is unlikely to be with `gcloud` and more likely to be with a long-running ssh connection. You could confirm this by ssh'ing to the VM using the `google_compute_engine` key directly. If the behavior is the same, then it's probably not `gcloud`

Comment: You can add `--ssh-flag="-vvv" ` to `gcloud compute ssh ${INSTANCE} ...` to get verbose logging. You can add the flag directly too, e.g. `ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine $(whoami)@${INSTANCE} -vvv ...`

Comment: For debugging you can use verbosity [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--verbosity)